# how to set View gravity based on different orientations (0, 90, 180, 270)?

Tags: android

Is it possible to load different xml layouts based on its current orientation instead of just by portrait/landscape?

I am writing an app with a front-facing camera feature.
When the device is rotated 180 degrees, my CAPTURE button is now right beside the camera. This causes the camera to be blocked by my fingers when i try to click the CAPTURE button.

In my landscape XML, the button is always to the right. I like to align it towards the home button (away from the front camera).

If it cannot be done via XML, is there another way to achieve this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <SurfaceView
       android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_primary"
        android:padding="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_black_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/icons" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you fix your activity orientation to landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can design a xml file with same name separately for landscape view, create a folder with name layout-land and place the xml there.
android will automatically reload the xml

or

you can set gravity by overriding onConfigurationChanged method like this

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
 super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}`
```

Edit:

```
private int getScreenOrientation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
    // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
        (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "portrait.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;          
        }
    }
    return orientation;
}
```

Comment: no, i meant to have 2 different xmls for landscape. one where the camera is to the right, another where the camera is to the left.

Comment: ok now i understand I am making an edit in my post take a look